# Set Core Data Object to NSSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have two entities in my database.

book and author.

book has a property "isBy", which has a to-many relationship to authors.

author has a property "books", which has a to-many relationship with books.

What i want to do is set the "isBy" definition of book. What I have tried is creating an NSSet and loading it with Author objects. I then do this:

```
NSMutableSet* authors;
//fill up set with authors
book.isBy = authors;
```

This isn't setting the isBy property correctly. Can anyone figure out the proper way to do this and tell my why my way is wrong?

Answer (score -2):

if you look at the .h file for book you can see two methods:

- (void)addIsByObject:(Author *)value;
- (void)addIsBy:(NSSet *)values;

These are the key.